# React native: useSelector redux is empty

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am new and i want to using react native to create android application so after creating project i installed redux and redux thunk and do every config that redux wants to work .

I create a action file :

```js
    export const GETSURVEYOR = 'GETSURVEYOR';
    
    const URL = "http://192.168.1.6:3000/";
    
    export const fetchSurveyor = () => {
        return async dispatch => {
            const controller = new AbortController();
            const timeout = setTimeout(
                () => { controller.abort(); },
                10000,
            );
            const response = await fetch(`${URL}GetSurveyorList`,
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({}),
                    signal: controller.signal
                });
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            const resData = await response.json();
    
            dispatch({
                type: GETSURVEYOR,
                surveyorList: resData.SurveyorList
            });
        }
    }
```

after that i create reducer to handle this data :

```js
    import {GETSURVEYOR} from '../actions/surveyor'
    
    const initialState = {
        surveyorList: []
    }
    
    export default (state = initialState, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case GETSURVEYOR:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    surveyorList: action.surveyorList
                };
```

Now i am using by `useSelector, useDispatch` from `'react-redux` .

```js
    import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
    import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
    
    import * as surveyorActions from '../store/actions/surveyor';
    
    export default () => {
        const [surveyorCount, setSurveyorCount] = useState(0);
        const survayers = useSelector(state => state.surveyor.surveyorList);
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    
        const loadSurvayer = useCallback(async () => {
            await dispatch(surveyorActions.fetchSurveyor());
            console.log('run use Callback');
            console.log('returned :', survayers );
            // setSurveyorCount(survayers.length);
        }, [dispatch]);
    
        useEffect(() => {
            loadSurvayer();
        }, [dispatch]);
    
        return [loadSurvayer, surveyorCount];
    }
```

When for first time this paged is rendered , of course that `survayers` is empty  but after fetch data in action and set state to reducer , `survayers`  nut to be an empty.
But i get empty still ? I am sure data is fetched from services but i got empty from `survayers` ?

```
 LOG  Running "RNAuditMngm" with {"rootTag":1}
 LOG  run use Callback
 LOG  returned : []
 LOG  run use Callback
 LOG  returned : []
```

if i change my useEffect code to this:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        loadSurvayer();
    }, [dispatch,survayers]);
```

I fall to loop !!!! How could i change code without loop?

Comment: In useSelector shouldn't you read surveyerList like this state.surveyorList ?. your state doesn't have any object named surveyor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think everything works fine, but you're not using the `console.log` in the right place. When you run the `loadSurvayer` the `survayers` is empty. It is empty even the second time because you are not passing it as a dependency in the `useEffect` hook. And like you said, if you pass it as a dependency, then it causes an infinite loop, and that's right because whenever the `survayers` change, that function will be called again and so on.

So, here's what you have to do:

1. Remove the `dispatch` dependency from your `useEffect` hook.
2. Change the `console.log`'s outside of the `loadSurvayer` function.
3. Remove the `await` from the `dispatch` call because it is synchronous.

Here's how to modify your code to work the right way:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import * as surveyorActions from '../store/actions/surveyor';

export default () => {
    const [surveyorCount, setSurveyorCount] = useState(0);
    const survayers = useSelector(state => state.surveyor.surveyorList);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();


    const loadSurvayer = useCallback(async () => {
        dispatch(surveyorActions.fetchSurveyor()); // Remove the `await`
        console.log('run use Callback');
        // setSurveyorCount(survayers.length);
    }, [dispatch]);

    useEffect(() => {
        loadSurvayer();
    }, []); // <-- remove the `dispatch` from here.

    console.log('returned :', survayers ); // <-- Move the console log here

    return [loadSurvayer, surveyorCount];
}
```

Improvement bonus and suggestion: remove the `surveyorCount` state variable because you don't actually need it as you can return the count directly.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import * as surveyorActions from '../store/actions/surveyor';

export default () => {
    // Remove the `surveyorCount`
    //const [surveyorCount, setSurveyorCount] = useState(0);
    const survayers = useSelector(state => state.surveyor.surveyorList);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();


    const loadSurvayer = useCallback(async () => {
        dispatch(surveyorActions.fetchSurveyor()); // Remove the `await`
        console.log('run use Callback');
        // setSurveyorCount(survayers.length);
    }, [dispatch]);

    useEffect(() => {
        loadSurvayer();
    }, []); // <-- remove the `dispatch` from here.

    console.log('returned :', survayers ); // <-- Move the console log here

    //return [loadSurvayer, surveyorCount];
    return [loadSurvayer, survayers.length]; // <-- Use `survayers.length` instead of `surveyorCount`
}
```

Comment: I want say thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

In useSelector shouldn't you read surveyerList like this state.surveyorList ?. your state doesn't have any object named surveyor but you are currently reading like state.surveyor.surveyorList

Comment: Ok, but how could i use of `useSelector ` ? @AyyappaGollu

Comment: useSelector(state => state.surveyorList). try this. although I never used useselector myself.

Comment: Dude in  `state.surveyor`  surveyor is added to `combineReducers` in app file from redux library . i have a few reducer file added to `combineReducer`. @AyyappaGollu